# JSX callback without passing individual props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, callback, jsx

I wonder if there is a way to replicate same usage of js callback's in JSX like:

```js
[1,2,3].map(console.log) // Here map iterator takes care of passing values to iteratee.
```

Is there a similar way to pass component like that, ie. rather then this:

```
<List data={data} renderItem={item => <Post {...item} />} />
```

something like this:

```
<List data={data} renderItem={<Post/>} />
```

Comment: If you see props are very similar to callback functions, you pass something and you use it in children. Let say you pass a function from parent to child, child will call that function same as you pass a callback function to a function A and A will call the callback function later.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ok, just found out you can use components as plain js functions:

```
 <List data={data} renderItem={Post} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but speaking from experience this leads to pain and bad design later on once these components grow and requirements change. The List component becomes more esoteric, and it's hard to find where things should be.

For instance, if you wanted to do something as simple as render a sponsored `Post`, the code becomes needlessly complex:

```
// Index.js
<List data={data} renderItem={Post} renderSponsoredItem={SponsoredPost} />
```

```
// List.js
function List({ data, renderItem, renderSponsoredItem }) {
  <div className={styles.list}>
    data.map(dataItem => {
      if (dataItem.sponsored) {
        return renderSponsoredItem(dataItem);
      } else {
        return renderItem(dataItem);
      }
    });
  </div>
}
```

...and in a way, this ends up looking not like React at all, and doesn't harness the ease-of-use and readability thats possible with React.

An alternative could look something like:

```
// Index.js
<List>
  {data.map(dataItem => {
    if (dataItem.sponsored) {
      return <SponsoredPost post={dataItem} />;
    } else {
      return <Post post={dataItem} />
    } 
  })
</List>
```

```
// List.js
function List({ children }) {
  <div className={styles.list}>
    {children}
  </div>
}
```

I've found the first form to lend itself to unreadable code and unworkable, unreadable components in the long term, and the latter to be much easier to read/work with.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but imho If we look from parent component level (in this case List) it doesn't need to know about the details of what type of Post it should render. You can basically have conditional logic in Post to determine if the current data element is going to be SponsoredPost or some other type of Post. Also, List is actually a component from https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/list/overview#list

Comment: Like I said, you can go in that direction, but it almost universally leads to more confusing code and bad component design. 

You're obviously constrained by library code, but IMO the component design in that library is pretty poor.